# How to check if two dates are the same with timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two dates. One I get from the database, the other is which one I want to pass. How can I check if these two are the same? These are timestamp with time zones

In this case they are the same.

```
% timestamp_coloumn is my column where the value is in it
SELECT *
    FROM public.tbl_text
WHERE ('2021-06-02T06:33:51.485Z' - timestamp_coloumn) = 0;

%What I hand over: 2021-06-02T06:33:51.485Z

%Stands in the database: 2021-06-02 06:33:51.485093+00 = timestamp_coloumn
```

Comment: `WHERE '2021-06-02T06:33:51.485Z'::timestamptz = "timestamp"`

Comment: @Stefanov.sm thank you very much! But what is `"timestamp"`

Comment: "timestamp" is a quoted name because timestamp is a reserved word. You changed it to `timestamp_coloumn`, so `WHERE '2021-06-02T06:33:51.485Z'::timestamptz = timestamp_coloumn`.

Comment: `WHERE ('2021-06-02T06:33:51.485Z'::timestamptz  = timestamp_coloumn);` If I write it like this, the request is empty, but something should come out, because the timestamps are the same.

Comment: Well, not really, there is 093 ms difference.

Comment: But they should be the same :/ I see the difference, but I think the other TimeStamp is truncated and hence this difference

Comment: Is there an option to somehow cut this to the same length so they are the "same"?

Comment: Use date_trunc as in the  answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
    FROM public.tbl_text
    WHERE 
      '2021-06-02T06:33:51.485Z'::timestamptz = 
       date_trunc('milliseconds', timestamp_coloumn);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and for your help. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing this as:

```
WHERE timestamp_coloumn >= '2021-06-02T06:33:51.485Z'::timestamp AND
      timestamp_coloumn < '2021-06-02T06:33:51.485Z'::timestamp + INTERVAL '1 millisecond'
```

Note that this is index and optimizer friendly.  If you have an index on `timestamp_column`, this might be very, very fast.